# How to return value from method that has an array in its parameter in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have this code but it doesn't work!

```
public class Trial
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        int average;
        int m = 0;

        int [] nums = {1,6,8,9,10,60,72};

        average = getAverage(int [] nums);
    }

    public static int getAverage(int [] a)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
            sum = sum +a[i];

        int avg = sum/a.length;
        return avg;
    }
}
```

Where is the problem ? I need to get the average of that array by calling a method that calculate the average.

Comment: Remove the declaration in the call, just pass "nums".

Comment: Also, consider using the expression: `for (int i : a) { sum += i; }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your method call:

```
average = getAverage(nums);
```

Answer (score 3):

I see two problems:

1. `average = getAverage(int [] nums)` should read `average = getAverage(nums)`.
2. The function returns an `int`. You might want to consider using floating-point math for the result. Otherwise you're truncating the answer to the nearest `int`.

Comment: Yeah it works! silly mistake :( Yeah, I need it to be as the nearest integer

Comment: to the nearest? so you need to make a Round or truncate or something because this line  int avg = sum/a.length; may raise you an exception when you get a floating point

Comment: @Mr. No, it won't throw an exception. It'll quietly truncate.

Comment: @Mr. - The entire thing is integer math, there's no way an exception will be thrown due to 'floating point'.  The only sort of exception that could be encountered is if the array is empty (divide by zero).  Explicitly invoking `Round()` _may_ be called for (although casting one or both operators would be necessary).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation didn't know about it, that it was called explicity, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
average = getAverage(int [] nums); //this is wrong

average = getAverage(nums); //this is right. Just sintaxis.
```

Answer (score 0):

`avg` can be a floating point value, but your implementation will always return integer.

Consider using floating point value for `sum` and `avg` and change return type to `double`.